# Dynamic Navigation Function in php in separate file

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a dynamic php navigation system that shows the active tab, but can not seem to make the showing the active tab part work. While I have found easier ways to do this, they all require the use of php in the original file. I would like to be able to just call a function that returns or echoes the navigation and sets the active page.
Any suggestions are super welcome!

**My index.php file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">    

<!-- Helps with rendering on different size machines -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Keeps user from scrolling -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<!-- Main CSS style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/mainStyle.css">

<!-- Import php form with functions for navigation-->

<title> Shoe Site </title>

</head>

<body>
    <?php
    require 'mainPhp.php'; 
    echo Navigation(); 
    ?>

        <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Welcome to the Shoe Site</h1>
            <p class="lead">Description of site.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- use this on items that are on sale
        <h3><span class="label label-primary" width="auto"> Items on Sale </span></h3>
        -->

        <!-- On Sale columns -->
        <h2 class="sectionHeader"> Shoes on Sale Below </h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Description</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Add to cart &raquo;</a></p>
                <p><span class="label label-primary" width="auto">Sale! </span> </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        </br>
        <hr>
        </br>

        <!-- Regular Item columns -->
        <h2 class="sectionHeader"> Entire Shoe Catalog </h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Description</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Add to cart &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Site footer -->
        </br>
        <hr>
        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Brianna Jones XD</p>
        </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My mainPhp.php file:**

```
<?php
function PageName() {
  return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}

$current_page = PageName();

function Navigation(){
//can not get the page to stay active
$current_page = PageName();
echo ('
    <div class="container">
        <div class= "masthead">
            <nav>
                <h1 class="text-muted">Shoe Site</h2>
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class="$current_page == \'index.php\' ? \'active\':NULL"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="$current_page == \'cart.php\' ? \'active\':NULL"><a href="cart.php">Cart</a></li>
                    <li class="$current_page == \'admin.php\' ? \'active\':NULL"><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
');
}
?>
```

Comment: I think @mi6crazyheart 's answer is about correct. But just curious why you assign $current_page twice, from outside and inside Navigation();

Comment: Ahh, that was a mistake I was trying some different things before I posted and must have missed that when I was reverting back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code for your `mainPhp.php` file

```
<?php
function PageName() {
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}

$current_page = PageName();

function Navigation(){
    //can not get the page to stay active
    $current_page = PageName();

    echo '<div class="container">';
        echo '<div class= "masthead">';
            echo '<nav>';
                echo '<h1 class="text-muted">Shoe Site</h2>';

                echo '<ul class="nav nav-justified">';
                    $btnActiveClass = ($current_page=='index.php') ? 'active' : 'NULL';
                    echo '<li class="'.$btnActiveClass.'"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>';

                    $btnActiveClass = ($current_page=='cart.php') ? 'active' : 'NULL';
                    echo '<li class="'.$btnActiveClass.'"><a href="index.php">Cart</a></li>';

                    $btnActiveClass = ($current_page=='admin.php') ? 'active' : 'NULL';
                    echo '<li class="'.$btnActiveClass.'"><a href="index.php">Admin</a></li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            echo '</nav>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Missing semicolon on " echo '</ul>' " and last "echo '</div>'" . Other parts should work.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have fixed it.